# Pass Variable Number of Parameters to Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, parameterized

How does one pass a random number of parameters to a query? The below code blocks show what was attempted.  All of the failures displayed bool(false).  For testing, three integers are used to represent ids.

The query from item 1 was manually executed in pgAdminIII, and was successful.  The query from item 2 and 4 was echo'd and compared.  They look close as intended, but the parameters are not binding.

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE id = ANY('{1,2,3}'::int[]);
SELECT column FROM table WHERE id = ANY('{?,?,?}'::int[])
```

1) This works. The desire is that the any clause will be 1-N numbers:

```
$sql = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE id = ANY('{1,2,3}'::int[])";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

echo var_dump($result);

$dbh = null;
```

2) This fails:

```
$values = array(1,2,3);
$placeHolders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?'));

$sql = sprintf("SELECT column FROM table WHERE id = ANY('{%s}'::int[])", $placeHolders);

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($values);
$result = $sth->fetch();

echo var_dump($result);

$dbh = null;
```

3) This fails:

```
$values = array(':qwer' => 1, ':asdf' => 2, ':zxcv' => 3);

$sql = "SELECT colum FROM table WHERE id = ANY(\'{ :qwer , :asdf , :zxcv }\'::int[])";  //Below error caused if single quote not escaped.

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($values); // Invalid parameter number: :qwer if single quotes not escaped.
$result = $sth->fetch();

echo var_dump($result);

$dbh = null;
```

4) This fails (explicitly binding the parameters):

```
$values = array(1,2,3);
$placeHolders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?'));

$sql = sprintf("SELECT query FROM nc_reports WHERE id = ANY('{%s}'::int[])", $placeHolders);

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$i = 1;
foreach($values as $val)
{
    //$sth->bindParam($i, $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindValue($i, $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $i++;
}
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch();

echo var_dump($result);

$dbh = null;
```

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/php-pdo-can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: I am curious, did you ever try to echo out the result of your program? Program that creates a query I mean. Is it any different from the handwritten one? if so - what's the difference?

Comment: @FoolishSeth: Thank you for the heads up.  I changed my query from ANY to IN, and it works.

Comment: @Your Common Sense: I did echo the queries after creating the parameter placeholders.  I have not figured out how to get the query after inserting the parameter values to be able to see the completed query string.

Comment: @FoolishSeth: I need to correct my above comment.  It returns the first id encountered.  So out of the three (1, 2, 3), only the record for the first is returned.  I tried both binding the parameters, and then just $execute($values), and both returned the same thing (1 record).  Again, thanks for pointing me to something, it was a partial fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to generate the query yourself:

```
$values = array(1,2,3);
// Generate the query
$params = substr(str_repeat("?,", sizeof($values)), 0, -1);

$sql = "SELECT query FROM nc_reports WHERE id IN ($params)";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($values); $i++)
{
    $sth->bindValue($i+1, $values[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
$sth->execute();
// Iterate over the results
while (($result = $sth->fetch()) !== FALSE) {
    echo var_dump($result);
}
$dbh = null;
```

Comment: Thank you for the example.  I had attempted to use the IN clause last night before showing my below down-voted solution.  The ANY clause returns 0 results, the IN clause returns one result (the first encountered).  The only way so far I have found to get all results is my currently down-voted solution.  I'll have to RTFM on pgAdmin tonight and figure out how to access the log to see what values are hitting the server.  Thanks for taking a look at the issue.

Comment: @Dave, that's because you need to iterate over the results. I edited my answer to show how (the loop).

Answer (score -2):

@FoolishSeth: Thank you for pointing me to the answer. I was unable to understand what ws being discussed at first due to formatting of code. I was able to make it work, but not using ANY (no result) or IN (only the first result).

The execute and fetch were moved into the loop, and each item from the $values array is queried individually and added to a $results array.

```
$values = array(1,2,3);

$sql = "SELECT column FROM table WHERE id = ?";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$result = array();

foreach($values as $key => $val)
{
    $sth->bindValue(1, $val, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
    $result[$key] = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
}

echo var_dump($result);
```

The above returned the three rows as desired.  I did not have an opportunity to test this against large $values[], but for the small amount of records intended this should work.

Comment: this is apparently **not** a solution

Comment: this is a really bad solution, because you are going to send a lots of queries to the database, while you could send just one (as in my answer).

Comment: @MatheusOl: Your solution only returns the first record encountered, not all records for the ids in the $values array.